# Angular2 Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) from some GET requests

Tags: angular, cors, angular-http, preflight

I am using Angular2, Communicating with a rest API, settings the header like so:

```
import { Headers } from '@angular/http';

export const contentHeaders = new Headers();
contentHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
contentHeaders.append('Authorization', localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
```

Get request like `items/` and POST request works, but when making GET requests for one item, like: `items/579212a6541d5626732619c3` the server respond with a server error `Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

I thought those get requests are the same, but maybe they are not ? Any solutions ?

Comment: Sounds like the server doesn't provide the correct response to the CORS request.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect + says that you are probably being redirected from that particular request. Are you sure that the ID of item is handled correctly on a backend?

Comment: Yes it is, Well I had to put `/` at the end of the URL!

Comment: Yes, don't forget to check the URL pattern of your API